# In Azure Anomaly Detector API,Why is changing sensitivity parameter is not changing response output of detected anomaly?

Tags: azure, azure-anomaly-detector

with reference to notebook available on [Azure-site](https://notebooks.azure.com/AzureAnomalyDetection/projects/anomalydetector),
I have created an experiment, where am pushing some 5000 records of the parameter. I tried changing `sensitivity` from `90` to `25` but I can-not see any changes on output bokeh plot.

#### sensitivity = 95

[image]

#### sensitivity = 25

[image]

I even checked the JSON that is being loaded before running Anomaly-Detector API and sensitivity value is being updated as per required format.
Can you suggest me what could be the reason? Where should I look into to resolve the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What are the other parameters you set? From the figure you attached, it seems that your data is periodic. Can you try to set the `period` value, and set `maxAnomalyRatio` to a small value?